# Помогите разобраться с checkBox при попытке сохранить пользователя на устройстве android

Tags: android

У меня в приложении есть форма логина, под которой есть чекбокс, при выборе которого пользователь подтверждает что хотел-бы в следующий раз не логинится повторно. Вот код выбора checkBox:

```
public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {
        CheckBox user = findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    if (user.isChecked()) {
        has_vis = getSharedPreferences("hasVisited", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = has_vis.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("hasVisited", true);
        editor.apply();
    } else {
        has_vis = getSharedPreferences("hasVisited", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = has_vis.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("hasVisited", false);
        editor.apply();
    }
    }
```

дальше в  onCreate у меня выполняется проверка переменной hasVisited:

```
sp = getSharedPreferences(REFRESH_TOKEN, MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean hasVisited = sp.getBoolean("hasVisited", false);


        if (hasVisited) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SecondScreen.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            try {
                submitBtn = findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
                submitBtn.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.button));
                submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        sendPost();
                    }
                });

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
                        SendLogcatMail(thread, ex);
                    }
                });


            }
        }
```

но у меня почему-то не сохраняет значение переменной и дальше при каждом запуске все-равно приходится логинится. Я вижу три возможных источника проблемы - либо я сохраняю неправильно переменную, либо я неправильно считываю значение переменной, либо я опять где-то протупил. Но без чекбокса у меня проходило сохранение нормально, и проверка работала при старте программы тоже правильно, если так рассуждать то у меня неправильно сохраняет значение переменной, но вроде все ок. Помогите найти ошибку, если она есть.

Comment: Проблема в том, что у Вас на каждое значение своё хранилище и Вы в них запутались - записываете в одно (`getSharedPreferences("hasVisited", 0)`), а получаете из другого (`getSharedPreferences(REFRESH_TOKEN, MODE_PRIVATE)`) - это разные файлы. Для Вашей задачи можно использовать одно хранилище и все значения заносить в него.

Comment: То есть можно создавать одно хранилище и просто туда кидать переменные с  определенными идентификаторами?

Comment: Да, можно - просто в методах `get/put` используете для каждого значения свой ключ (REFRESH_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN, и т.п.)

Comment: @woesss если не сложно напишите простенький пример или туториал, потому-что я приблизительно понял что вы имеете в виду, но могу как всегда неправильно реализовать))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У чекбокс есть метод `setOnCheckedChangeListener`

```
CheckBox user = findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

user.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
            // Выполняем код, если бокс активен
            } else {
             // Выполняем код, если бокс не активен
            }
            // Сохраняем состояние бокса
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = has_vis.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("hasVisited", isChecked).apply;
        }
    });
```

И потом где нужно получаем состояние:

```
boolean hasVisited = sp.getBoolean("hasVisited", false);
```

Задаем это состояние чекбоску:

```
user.setChecked(hasVisited);
```

И если требуется по полученному состоянию чекбоска делаем условие на выполнение определенных действий:

```
if (hasVisited) {
// Выполняем код, если бокс активен
} else {
// Выполняем код, если бокс не активен
}
```

Таким образом, при каждом создадии активити/фрагмента, состоянием чекбокса будет переменная `hasVisited`, которая по стандарту равна `false`.